# Necessary and sufficient condition for a subgroup to be factor

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G =A \times B$, where I will call $A$ and $B$ as factors of group $G$.

For an example $Z_{21} =Z_7 \times Z_3$, $Z_3$ is a factor of group $Z_{21}$.

Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $A$ how to check whether $A$ is a factor of $G$ or not.

Here is my idea, find the $G/A$ and then set an homomorphism from $G/A$ to the group $G$.

**Question :** What is neccessary and sufficient conidtion for a subgroup to be a factor?

Comment: You may want to Google "semidirect prodoct". This is precisely the setting where you have a subgroup $H\leq G$ and a homomorphism $\phi: G\rightarrow G$ such that $\phi(G)=H$ and $\phi(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$.

Comment: @user1729 Is this gives a criteria for factor?

Comment: @ddddd Yes - by $\phi(G)=H$ I mean that the image of $\phi$ is precisely $H$. So if $N:=\ker(\phi)$ we have $G/N\cong H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is a direct factor of $G$ if and only if the following two conditions hold:

(i) $AC_G(A)=G$; and

(ii) $Z(A)$ has a complement in $C_G(A)$.

Note that $G = A \times B$, where $B$ is any complement of $Z(A)$ in $C_G(A)$.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It looks completely clear to me!

Comment: @ Derek Holt I mean the symbol $AC_G(A)$ or you mean $A \times C_G(A)$? and I am not getting difference between $Z(A)$ and $C_G(A)$

Comment: $AC_G(A) = \{ xy : x \in A, y \in C_G(A) \}$. This is standard notation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I believe it does not requires $G$ to be abelian. To me also difference between $Z(A)$ and $C_G(A)$ is not clear. If possible share a link or reference from where i can read more about this.

Comment: $Z(A) = C_A(A) =  C_G(A) \cap A$.

Comment: @ I check dummit and foote, Rotman but not able to find the above condition did you remember from where you have taken the above conditions.

Comment: The equivalence is very easy so I would not expect to find it in a book.

Answer (score 1):

For abelian group $G$, it's necessary and sufficient for a subgroup $A$ to be a factor that there is a homomorphism $G/A\to G$ such that when composed with the canonical projection $G\to G/A$, the homomorphism
$$
G/A\to G\to G/A
$$
is the identity on $G/A$. Dually, it's necessary and sufficient that there is a homomorphism $G\to A$ such that when composed with the inclusion $A\to G$, the homomorphism
$$
A\to G\to A
$$
is the identity on $A$.

In your example, for instance, we have $A = \Bbb Z_3$ and $G = \Bbb Z_{21}$. The relevant homomorphism $G\to A$ is given by
$$
1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19\mapsto1\\
2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20\mapsto 2\\
0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18\mapsto 0
$$
(also known as "reducing modulo $3$") while the relevant homomorphism $G/A\cong\Bbb Z_7\to \Bbb Z_{21}$ is given by
$$
a\mapsto 3a
$$

Comment: Thank, but $G$ can be non-abelian also.

Comment: @jjjaaaaaaaaa Well, then it's not so simple. In that case I actually don't know the answer.

Comment: Could know any you reference for the above answer so that i can read in a detail way?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma#Proof_for_the_category_of_abelian_groups) has a short article. It includes some advanced terminology, although I think you will be mostly OK with knowing that in this case, $0\to A\to G\to G/A\to 0$, where $0$ is the trivial group and all the arrows are the canonical homomorphisms (inclusions and quotients), is one case of what they call a "short exact sequence".

Comment: Those two "dual" conditions are not equivalent to each other in general. However, the conjunction of those two conditions does give the condition which the OP asks for, i.e. a necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ to be a direct factor.

Comment: @LeeMosher For abelian groups (which is what my answer is concerned with), they are equivalent. For non-abelian groups, the existence of the $A\to G\to A$ map is stronger and, as far as I can tell from the Wikipedia article, actually sufficient. Clearly it is necessary, since a product always has a projection homomorphisms onto each of its factors.